# Link to non http protocol from a Rails mailer template

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, email, hyperlink

I'd like to have a link in an email (opened on an iOS devise) open an iOS app.

I have Rails mailer template that contains a link, which opens the app 'myapp' on an iOS device:

```
<%= link_to 'Reset my password', "myapp://?password_reset_token=#{@token}" %>
```

This link is rendered properly when used in a regular view, displayed in a browser.

The problem is when the link is used in a mailer template it displays without the href:

```
<a href>Reset My password</a>
```

I get the same results when I put the `<a>` tag manually in the template instead of using `link_to`. Still results in blank href.

It seems that using any protocol other than `http` or `https` yields the same results.

Is there any way to make this non http link display properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I got around this was to adjust my url like this:

```
"myapp://myapp.com?password_reset_token=#{@token}"
```

The addition of the 'myapp.com' part made it work, and I can just ignore that part, and parse out the query params that I need.

Comment: Its not working for me, when I check mail in gmail the href remove from mail, it looks like `<a href>Reset My password</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Above solution do not work as
when I check mail in gmail the href remove from mail, it looks like `<a href>Reset My password</a>`

So I have done a workaround for it

I have redirected to a route and in that I embed script as below

```
<script> 
$(function(){
 window.location = "myapp://myapp.com"+window.location.search 
})()
</script>
```

so it will redirects with all parameters to the URI